# How to add second level menu in sb admin panel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using sb admin panel 2 in my application. I want to make second level menu in side menu, but when i do that, second level menu is always open. I want when I click first level menu then second menu appear. Not able to understand where is the problem.

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li class="sidebar-search">
                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /input-group -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Sudent <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="student/studentlistdb.php">Student</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="subject/subjectlistdb">Subject</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Routine <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
</div>
```

this code is present in my page header and added all js in my footer

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/morris-data.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `collapse` class to your second level

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
```

P.S
it looks like you are using SBAdmin V2 and not V1, should specify that.
Also, i would suggest to try copy/paste from their demo pages and modifying it to your likings.

[SBAdminV2 Live Preview](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/)

[SBAdminV2 Github page](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2) (Source, Documentation, and HELP! :) )

[SBAdminV1 Live Preview](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/)

**EDIT**
Seems to work fine with their exact code.

```html
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <script src="//blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: I already tried that but when i use that it is not working. second level not opening

Comment: Click RUN CODE SNIPPET a few times to see the result, there is some kind of SO issue with the code.

Comment: I thing problem is in my footer js. tell me where is the problem please

Comment: yes..I solved that.Thanks for your answer.The problem is in my footer.

Comment: You are not supplying the whole code that is related and it is very hard to find the issue like that. As i suggested in my answer, try copy/paste their original code and see if it works.